# using regex in text based value search in the page using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have to parse a web site that based on regex for `$x`  using p

```
<a href="">(001)</a>
<a href="">(002)</a>
<a href="">(003)</a>
<a href="">(004)</a>
<a href="">Hello1</a>
<a href="">Hello2</a>
<a href="">WOrld</a>
```

I am using  below code

`const xpathTxtArr = await page.$x("//*/a[contains(text(), 'Hello')]");` to fetch all links with `hello` text.

Similarly I want to know , if I can pass regular expression like `\d{3}` in `page.$x` expression to get the link handlers with pattern `(001)`?

Answer (score 3):

Well I could not find an answer . To grep the text I used `evaluate` function to get all the inner text.

here is the sample code

```
const result = await page.evaluate(async () => {
    console.log('Browser scope.');
    let elementTxtArr = [];
    document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach((a)=> {
       console.log(a.innerText);
       elementTxtArr.push(a.innerText);
    });
    return elementTxtArr;
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: After you did this, were you able to use regular expressions outside of the "result" function to find anything with the word "hello" ?  I'm working on something similar.  If i find a solution before you answer, i'll post it here.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may find help in this link:

https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#attribute-substrings

I haven't tried this yet, but maybe something like:

```
const result = await page.evaluate(async () => {
    console.log('Browser scope.');
    let elementTxtArr = [];
document.querySelectorAll('[href^="hello"]').forEach((a)=>{
    console.log(a.innerText);
    elementTxtArr.push(a.innerText);}); 
    return elementTxtArr;
});
console.log(result);
```